# C# Linq XML InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to create an XML file based on a .csv file. I figured I could use my old method for reading the .csv file and just replace some parts. However I get an exception saying:

> InvalidOperationException

Here is my code:

```
    public void LoadFile() {
        XDocument outputDocument = new XDocument();
        outputDocument.Add(new XElement("Inventory"));

        using (var fstream = File.OpenRead(FilePathProducts))
        using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(fstream)) {
            while (!fileReader.EndOfStream) {
                var readLine = fileReader.ReadLine();
                var words = readLine.Split(';');


                outputDocument.Add(
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XElement("Name", words[1]),
                        new XElement("Count", words[3]),
                        new XElement("Price", words[4]),
                        new XElement("Comment", "<Missing Value>"),
                        new XElement("Artist", "<Missing Value>"),
                        new XElement("Publisher", "Nintendo"),
                        new XElement("Genre", "<Missing Value>"),
                        new XElement("Year", words[0]),
                        new XElement("ProductID", words[2])
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        outputDocument.Save(FilePathResult);
    }
```

It says something about "a wrongfully structured document is created" (roughly translated.)

When I tried removing the loop, the output file only displayed a self-closing Inventory-tag. I expected it to be an open and close -tag. So I'm guessing something is wrong with line 3 of the code above.

Comment: A tip: You can use the [Localized Error Message Lookup](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Emt.aspx) to translate the error message from your language to english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to append your `Item` elements directly to the XML document and XML documents are not allowed to have more than one root element. That is why you are getting an error.

I presume you actually want to add them to the `Inventory` element, in which case you should do this:

```
public void LoadFile() {
    var outputDocument = new XDocument();
    var inventory = new XElement("Inventory");
    outputDocument.Add(inventory);

    using (var fstream = File.OpenRead(FilePathProducts))
    using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(fstream)) {
        while (!fileReader.EndOfStream) {
            var readLine = fileReader.ReadLine();
            var words = readLine.Split(';');


            inventory.Add(
                new XElement("Item",
                    new XElement("Name", words[1]),
                    new XElement("Count", words[3]),
                    new XElement("Price", words[4]),
                    new XElement("Comment", "<Missing Value>"),
                    new XElement("Artist", "<Missing Value>"),
                    new XElement("Publisher", "Nintendo"),
                    new XElement("Genre", "<Missing Value>"),
                    new XElement("Year", words[0]),
                    new XElement("ProductID", words[2])
                )
            );
        }
    }

    outputDocument.Save(FilePathResult);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. =)
Although.. Now the last line is giving me problem outputDocument.Save(FilePathResult);
It says something about "resulting in an invalid xml-document"?

Comment: @Phrosen What is the exact error? Sounds like you're using .NET in a non-English language so feel free to post it in its original language.

Comment: Sorry. I just realized I had missed a line of code. It works now. Thank you. =)